# How to add UINavigation to a custom RootViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, nsuserdefaults

I've stored the user ID in an `NSUserDefault`. My app is under `UINavigationController` means all `ViewController` are connected to a `UINavigationController`. Now if user is not logged in it should show the first screen which is the login or register. But when user signs in, app should show the home screen as root. Here is what I'm doing in `AppDelegate.m`:

```
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:USERID] == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"User is not logged in");
// default scenario will run i.e. login
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"User ID: %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:USERID]);
            HomeViewController *home = (HomeViewController *)[mainStoryboard
                                                                         instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"HomeViewController"];

            [self.window setRootViewController:home];
        }
```

So when it shows the screen of `home` there is no navigation bar on it. So what should I do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HomeViewController *home = (HomeViewController *)[mainStoryboard
                                                                     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"HomeViewController"];     
UINavigationController *homeNavViewCtrl  = [[ UINavigationController alloc ] initWithRootViewController:home ];

[self.window setRootViewController:homeNavViewCtrl];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `HomeViewController` directly as the `rootViewController`, so it is not embedded in a navigation controller (navigation controllers are what provide the navigation bar, so this is why you are not seeing one).

To use a navigation controller, in your storyboard embed `HomeViewController` in a `UINavigationController` (**Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller**), and give that navigation controller an identifier (e.g. "HomeNavigationController"). Then, in your code:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeNavigationController"];
[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
```

Alternatively, you can embed your `HomeViewController` in a navigation controller programmatically:

```
HomeViewController *homeVC = (HomeViewContller *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"]
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: homeVC]
[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 LoginViewController *loginController=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginController"]; //or the homeController
UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:loginController];
self.window.rootViewController=navController;
```